# Cannot open input file Resources.res

Tags: masm, masm64

Please help me on this problem i have searched a lot and found no answer when i build any project in MASM64 i get this error

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\Users\emad\Desktop\EmadMASM\Win64App\Release\Resource.res'
```

I have tried many ML64.exe files and rc.exe files and i couldn't solve the problem
I have tried every solution even i have installed new windows but the problem is same

```
extrn ExitProcess: PROC
extrn MessageBoxA: PROC



includelib user32.lib
includelib kernel32.lib

; *************************************************************************
; Our data section. Here we declare our strings for our message box
; *************************************************************************
.data
    strTitle    db "64-bit",0
    strMessage  db "Hello World!",0

; *************************************************************************
; Our executable assembly code starts here in the .code section
; *************************************************************************
.code

WinMainCRTStartup PROC

    sub     rsp,28h         ; shadow space, aligns stack
    mov     rcx,0           ; hWnd = HWND_DESKTOP
    lea     rdx,strMessage  ; LPCSTR lpText
    lea     r8,strTitle     ; LPCSTR lpCaption
    mov     r9d,0           ; uType = MB_OK


    call    MessageBoxA     ; call MessageBox API function


    mov     ecx,eax
    call    ExitProcess

WinMainCRTStartup ENDP
End
```

Comment: Show the commands you use to assemble and link your program.

Comment: i use install64 from masm32.net to compile 64 bit programs and  i get this error